# It is not outputting any rows for my query result, why is this?

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays

When I push the submit button to submit the form, there are no records being displayed in my query result. I don't know why this is. I know the query is correct as I have tested it before but when I have included the WHERE clause it doesn't work, but I am sure this is the right code when trying to retrieve rows depending on what is entered in the form.

Also I am trying to display StudentAnswer in the array as AnswerContent but when I do this AnswerContent is only displayed for each AnswerId. How do I do it to display it for each StudentAnswer?. StudentAnswer is the same as AnswerId as whichever answer is selected it will retrieve the answer by its id and store it in the StudentAnswer field. Please help.

Below is my code:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head>
    <title>Exam Q & A</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <?php

  $username="xxx";
  $password="xxx";
  $database="mobile_app";

  mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);
  @mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");

  foreach (array('sessionid','questionno','studentid','orderfield') as $varname) {
    $$varname = (isset($_POST[$varname])) ? $_POST[$varname] : '';
  }

  switch ($orderfield) {
    case 'orderquestionno':
      $orderfield = 'q.QuestionNo'; 
      $ordername = 'Question Number';
      break;
    case 'orderstudentid':
      $orderfield = 'sa.StudentId'; 
      $ordername = 'Student Username';
      break;
   case 'orderwhole':
      $orderfield = 'q.SessionId AND q.QuestionNo'; 
      $ordername = 'Session ID and Question Number';
      break;
    case 'ordersessionid':
    default:
      $orderfield = 'q.SessionId';
      $ordername = 'Session ID';
      break;
  }

?>

<h1>MOBILE EXAM QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS SEARCH</h1>
<p><strong>NOTE: </strong>If a search box is left blank, then the form will search for all data under that specific field</p>

<form action="exam_QA.php" method="post" name="sessionform">        <!-- This will post the form to its own page"-->
  <p>Session ID: <input type="text" name="sessionid" value="<?php echo $sessionid; ?>" /></p>      <!-- Enter Session Id here-->
  <p>Question Number: <input type="text" name="questionno" value="<?php echo $questionno; ?>" /></p>      <!-- Enter Question Number here-->
  <p>Student Username: <input type="text" name="studentid" value="<?php echo $studentid; ?>" /></p>      <!-- Enter User Id here-->
  <p>Order Results By:
    <select name="orderfield">
      <option value="ordersessionid"<?php if ($orderfield == 'q.SessionId') echo ' selected="selected"' ?>>Session ID</option>
      <option value="orderquestionno"<?php if ($orderfield == 'q.QuestionNo') echo ' selected="selected"' ?>>Question Number</option>
      <option value="orderstudentid"<?php if ($orderfield == 'sa.StudentId') echo ' selected="selected"' ?>>Student Username</option>
      <option value="orderwhole"<?php if ($orderfield == 'q.SessionId AND q.QuestionNo') echo ' selected="selected"' ?>>Session ID and Question Number</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" /></p>
</form>

<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $query = "
     SELECT *, a2.AnswerContent as StudentAnswerContent
     FROM Question q
    INNER JOIN StudentAnswer sa ON q.QuestionId = sa.QuestionId
    LEFT JOIN Answer a ON (sa.QuestionId = a.QuestionId AND a2.CorrectAnswer = 1) 
    LEFT JOIN Answer a2 ON (sa.QuestionId = a2.QuestionId AND a2.AnswerId = sa.StudentAnswer) 
      WHERE
        ('".mysql_real_escape_string($sessionid)."' = '' OR q.SessionId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($sessionid)."')
      AND
        ('".mysql_real_escape_string($questionno)."' = '' OR q.QuestionNo = '".mysql_real_escape_string($questionno)."')
      AND
        ('".mysql_real_escape_string($studentid)."' = '' OR sa.StudentId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($studentid)."')
      ORDER BY $orderfield ASC";

    $num = mysql_num_rows($result = mysql_query($query));
    mysql_close();

?>

<p>
  Your Search:
  <strong>Session ID:</strong> <?php echo (empty($sessionid)) ? "'All Sessions'" : "'$sessionid'"; ?>,
  <strong>Question Number:</strong> <?php echo (empty($questionno)) ? "'All Questions'" : "'$questionno'"; ?>,
  <strong>Student Username:</strong> <?php echo (empty($studentid)) ? "'All Students'" : "'$studentid'"; ?>,
  <strong>Order Results By:</strong> '<?php echo $ordername; ?>'
</p>
<p>Number of Records Shown in Result of the Search: <strong><?php echo $num ?></strong></p>
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
  <th>Session ID</th>
  <th>Question Number</th>
  <th>Question</th>
  <th>Correct Answer</th>
  <th>StudentAnswer</th>
  <th>Correct Answer Weight</th>
  <th>Student Answer Weight</th>
  <th>Student ID</th>
  </tr>
  <?php

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    if ( $row['StudentAnswer'] == $row['AnswerId'] ) {   $row['StudentAnswerWeight'] = $row['Weight%']; } else {   $row['StudentAnswerWeight'] = '0'; } 
    $row['StudentAnswer'] == $row['AnswerContent'];
        echo "
  <tr>
  <td>{$row['SessionId']}</td>
  <td>{$row['QuestionNo']}</td>
  <td>{$row['QuestionContent']}</td>
  <td>{$row['AnswerContent']}</td>
  <td>{$row['StudentAnswerContent']} </td>
  <td>{$row['Weight%']}</td>
  <td>{$row['StudentAnswerWeight']}</td>
  <td>{$row['StudentId']}</td>
  </tr>";
    }
  ?>
</table>

<?php
  }
?>
```

Thank You :)

Comment: Have you tried to do a var_dump when you have the clausole WHERE?

Comment: yes I did try that got nothing. Before the left joins I did inner joins and it worked but I go told to do it this way instead

Comment: You have to give us more info in order to help you.

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to the top and put `or die(mysql_error())` at the end of each mysql call so that you can get more information about any errors occurring.  Then note then in your post.  Is `$num` (the number of rows) coming out non-zero?

Answer (score 2):

Your first `LEFT JOIN` is referencing an alias `a2` which doesn't exist yet at that point, because it is joined later in the next `LEFT JOIN`:

```
LEFT JOIN Answer a ON (sa.QuestionId = a.QuestionId AND a2.CorrectAnswer = 1)
                                                        ^^ invalid
```

I'm guessing that reference to `a2` is supposed to actually be `a`.  Note that if you had error reporting turned on in your development envrionment (`error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the top of the page), you would easily catch this because you would get the following error message when trying to run the query:

> Unknown column 'a2.CorrectAnswer' in 'on clause'

Demonstration: http://sqlize.com/8Wjawg6g4N